# Why do I have to stash / commit my changes before switching branches?

Tags: git

I find this to be annoying because I would like to quickly switch branches and do something and then switch back to what I was working on before. I realize I can stash and then retrieve stash, but then I have to type those lines every time :/

Is there any way to avoid having to do this?

I also find it annoying because I keep about 5 or 10 feature branches and it gets hard to manage which ones have a stash that needs to be retrieved and which ones are good to keep working on as they are.

Comment: Git probably has no way of knowing the state of a branch without a commit or a stash, so it wouldn't know how to rebuild the state of the repo...

Comment: This is not a good answer, but sometimes I just have more than one version of my repository pulled down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `git checkout`'s `--merge`(`-m`) option.
Using it causes a three-way merge to be done when switching branches. You may need to resolve merge conflicts if these occur.

As to why this occurs, the manual states

> When switching branches, if you have local modifications to one or
>   more files that are different between the current branch and the
>   branch to which you are switching, the command refuses to switch
>   branches in order to preserve your modifications in context.

See the [`git checkout` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html) for more details

Answer (score 8):

One way to make this easier is to use something like [Legit](https://frostming.github.io/legit/). One of the commands I like from Legit is `git sw`:

> ```
> $ git sw <branch>
> # Switches to branch. Stashes and restores unstaged changes.
> ```

Legit stores the stash with a description that follows a particular naming convention. That way, when you use `git sw` to return to the first branch, it can automatically unstash the changes saved for that branch.

[Update June 2023] Note that Git itself now has its own [`git switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch/) command, which does not automatically stash uncommitted changes.

Comment: +1 I believe this is much more in the sense of what the OP asked. I was about to post some code which basically does this because I did not know about legit.

Comment: That git-legit url appears to be a squatter. [frostming/legit](https://frostming.github.io/legit/) might be the same project. It has a `git sw` command that autostashes.

Comment: It's kind of funny (or perhaps unlucky) that since this answer was written, `git switch` has become a real command in Git which should now be preferred over `git checkout`.  Nowadays this either wouldn't work, or would be confusing.

Answer (score 3):

I find myself in your same scenario every day:

> I keep about 5 or 10 feature branches and it gets hard to manage which ones have a stash that needs to be retrieved and which ones are good to keep working on as they are.

For me the most effective solution is also the simplest (and alluded to in the question title):

**Commit your in-progress changes!**

I always write my *real* commits with a capital letter (following [this popular standard](https://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/)), and all of my in-progress commits start with a lowercase letter so they immediately stick out as needing an interactive rebase before I push. So if I need to switch branches to help someone out with something, I'll simply commit all of my changes and use a commit message such as:

> wip: rough draft of new CoolFeature API

BTW, I may also make that identical commit if I were stepping away to get some coffee too, even if I wasn't going to change branches.

**Interactive Rebase Tip:** When you commit, you can pass additional options such as:

```
git commit --squash=<commit-hash> # prep to squash this commit later
git commit --fixup=<commit-hash>  # prep to fixup this commit later
```

Note these will create commits for you with a commit message prefix of either "squash!" or "fixup!". For example, throughout a normal day I'll make some commits, as well as add some squash and fixup commits:

```
git log

5555555 Add thing 3
4444444 fixup! Update thing 2
3333333 squash! wip: rough draft of thing 1
2222222 Update thing 2
1111111 wip: rough draft of thing 1
0000000 Merge PR 12345: Do a thing (origin/main)
```

Note I named the commit titles such that I know that commit `1111111` is still in progress and the commit message needs to be eventually rewritten, compared with commit `2222222` which is "probably good and ready". I use squash to update commit `1111111` and change the message, and fixup to tweak commit `2222222` to squash without bothering to change the commit message.

Next time I `rebase -i` I'll use the `--autosquash` option and Git will follow the "squash" and "fixup" instructions. Here's a comparison of without, followed by with, the `--autosquash` option.

**Regular interactive rebase:**

```
git rebase origin/main -i

# Results in:
pick 1111111 wip: rough draft of thing 1
pick 2222222 Update thing 2
pick 3333333 squash! wip: rough draft of thing 1
pick 4444444 fixup! Update thing 2
pick 5555555 Add thing 3
```

**Interactive rebase with autosquash:**

```
git rebase origin/main -i --autosquash

# Results in:
pick 1111111 wip: rough draft of thing 1
squash 3333333 squash! wip: rough draft of thing 1
pick 2222222 Update thing 2
fixup 4444444 fixup! Update thing 2
pick 5555555 Add thing 3
```

As you can see, using `--autosquash` with the proper commit messages saves you a little bit of manual effort, as Git rearranges the commits for you in the rebase instructions.

Comment: `s into abcd123` could be written as `!squash abcd123` so [`git rebase --autosquash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---autosquash) will automatically reorder and label those actions. (Love using lowercase to make temp descriptions stand out!)

Comment: @idbrii wow- I completely forgot about this answer. Nowadays I usually use `--fixup` and `--autosquash`. It's possible I didn't know about autosquash yet when I wrote this answer, and it can perhaps use some updating. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @idbrii I just updated the answer to use autosquash.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid it using **git stash** to stash your changes. Then you can change branch, then restore the branch and getting back your changes:

```
$ git stash
$ git checkout other_branch
$ git checkout original_branch
$ git stash pop
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that to avoid stashing changes, you should stash changes?

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a solution for one of your problems but you can add a message to each stash in order to know which stash belongs to which branch. Doing it so you will allways easily know which branches have a stash and which don't.

For doing this just use this command:

```
git stash save -u branch1
```

where 'branch1' is the message or name that you give the stash