# Changes in one branch being reflected in all branches

Tags: git

The changes that I make are being reflected in other branches too.
I'm using VS Code.

I made some changes in a branch,say, `feature-1` and then I switched to the `main` branch using `git checkout main` and the changes were in the `main` branch and other branches too.  I tried to stash the changes on the `main` branch, then switched to `feature-1` and the changes removed by `stash` in the `main` branch  affected the code in `feature-1` branch too. I then did this in `feature-1` branch: `git stash pop` and the changes were made to other branches too.

What am I doing wrong here? It used to work just fine before.

Comment: Did you `git add` and `git commit` your changes?

Comment: @Wombatz I did neither

Comment: @Mayank that’s the problem right there

Comment: Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19793929/why-do-i-have-to-stash-commit-my-changes-before-switching-branches)

Comment: @Mayank then please remove your question.